# How to fix "The referrer https://www.googleapis.com/ does not match the referrer restrictions..."

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Here is what I have done. Keep in mind that I am logged in to the browser as admin for a G Suite account under the domain in question.

1. I go to PageSpeed Insights url https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
2. I enter my website into the box
3. ERROR: `The referrer https://www.googleapis.com/ does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions`

   a. How does google know that I had not configured a key?

   b. What key?

   c. there is no link to "my" API console (I did not know I had one)
4. Search API Console and get (eventually): https://console.developers.google.com/apis/
5. Stare and despair..."Page not viewable for organizations. To view this page, select a project" (what?). I see credentials (don't click it, not yet, i did, you'll regret it)
6. Looooooooong story short, I figure I have to create a project first.
7. At this point I have no idea what I am doing, WHAT I am creating or especially: WHY.
8. click on Enable Apis, select PageSpeed, Click on Create blah blah blah.
9. Now click Create credentials (we are back to the api page). This is a delightful nightmare... the important part, in "calling it from" USE: "a server", is the only one that works! (wonder why the other choices, specially "from browser" since that seems to me is what I was doing)
10. Now there is a key sitting there. Now what?
11. I go to point 1 and repeat this list with tiny variations 50 times

Domain in question: https://niagarafallsbus.com

Comment: Share your site URL I will have a look for you. Please edit your question to remove your rant as otherwise your question will get down-voted and closed, we all have bad days so I understand but this isn't constructive.

Comment: hmmm - it ran fine for me?? A super long shot but have you tried running it in incognito mode, it could be that being logged in has some strange behaviour (which makes it easier to diagnose).

Comment: Yes I tried incognito. But you made me think of the problem: ...Running on Brave Browser with "shields up". I did not have to do any of the above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLVED: I was using Brave Browser with "shields up".

Comment: Posting an answer and accepting it is sufficient. You don't need to edit your question or the title.